# Makefile Target: Cannot assign variable from loop

Tags: unix, for-loop, makefile

Problem is, `furl` doesn't get assigned value from `file` variable. If I use any plain text instead of `$$file`, it works. I have no idea why this doesn`t work.

Makefile:

```
test:
    @for file in $(shell pwd)/demo/*; do \
         $(eval furl := $(shell echo $$file)) \
         echo $(furl); \
    done
```

Im pretty sure this should be easy to fix, however I could not find a solution. Any ideas?

Im using the latest lubuntu OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have messed shell and Make variables in the recipe. I think `furl` should be shell variable. Something like this:

```
test:; @for file in demo/*; do \
         furl="`echo $$file`"; \
         echo "$$furl"; \
       done
```

In general you shouldn't assign Make variables in recipes. Obvious exception is `$(foreach)`.